# Que width obtiene canvas , naturalWidth o width?

Tags: canvas

Problema-> Después de redimensionar una imagen, canvas coge los píxeles de la imagen original.

Objetivo: 1-> resize de una imagen
2-> recortar la imagen redimensionada

1. Ésta función me modifica el width de la imagen y el heigth está en auto en css por lo que mantiene el ratio.

   ```
      function zoom2(event) {

         let imgWidth = window.getComputedStyle(event.target).getPropertyValue("width");
         let sizeValue = parseFloat(imgWidth.split('px')[0])

         if (event.deltaY < 0) {
             sizeValue += sizeValue < 3000 ? percent(sizeValue, 5) : 0;
         }
         else if (event.deltaY > 0) {
             sizeValue += sizeValue > 100 ? -percent(sizeValue, 5) : 0;
         }
         event.target.style.width = sizeValue + 'px';

     }
   ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Después de redimensionarla se la paso a la función con el drawImage(). Ésta función dibuja la imagen. El problema es que coge los 800 y 600 píxeles de la imagen original, no de la imagen después de haber sido redimensionada.

   ```
     function cropImg(img){

         const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
         const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

         img.addEventListener('load', ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 800, 600, 0 ,0, 400, 300))

     }
   ```

El resultado final es el que sigue. La imagen recortada es más grande de lo que debiera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]